# Xcode 8 - All Xcode Icons become empty

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

After upgraded to OSX Sierra Xcode 8 become like this.

Without menu icons Im completely blind and cant work at all. :<

[image]

Built success icon also Empty.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue with pdf icons - they don't show in storyboards, but work when I run the app. Couldn't find any solution yet

Comment: download xcode 8.0 from app store again.

Comment: i have downloaded xcode 8.0 / xcode 8.1 beta2 but still face the same issue :< .

Comment: It's a feature.